# Platinum engagement ring as oxidation catalyst

Tags: transition-metals, catalysis

I know platinum is used in the catalytic converter to oxidize pollutants.

- **For a pollutant ($\ce{N_xO}$, $\ce{CO}$, etc., your choice), I'd like to get an order-of-magnitude rate of catalysis, assuming partial pressures found in a major city (NYC?)**
- At room temperature (or body temperature)
- Let's assume the ring has 1 $\mathrm{cm^{2}}$  of surface area (I'm not rich, I assume  1 $\mathrm{cm^{2}}$ is reasonable)

Obviously using bulk platinum metal is an cost-ineffective method of catalysis, so it doesn't seem to be well studied. I know reaction is more efficient at high temperature, and while my girlfriend may figuratively be from Venus, I'd like to know the catalysis near STP. And perhaps a support is needed to prevent catalyst poisoning.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Feel free to visit the [help] if you have any questions about the site and how it works. Regarding your question, the conditions inside a catalytic converter are drastically different from that around a ring finger ;) Seriously, the air quality surrounding a person wearing a platinum ring will be indistinguishable from that around anyone else in the area.

Comment: I would assume the rate of catalysis is zero, pretty much exactly zero.